# Better way to show data for website, php-ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making this website-webservice where i really need a lot to print out data from DB and making some calculations in between.

I was considering which way would be the better-faster for the user.

1)Have a `XXXX.php` from where i through some AJAX functions by passing some parameters i would echo back the results and then the AJAX fill the certain divs.

2)Write the php straight out in the `page.php`. Thing is here that i will have to include a file that contains some `fucntions` that those calculations are going to need in which case if we go with way `No1` we won't have to.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to use Ajax or not really depends on your requirements and intended usage. If you use ajax, you do not need to refresh the page every time user filters/searches/edits: to display new results. That can mean a lot of waiting for the user, if the page is quite big.

On the other hand, when you use Ajax, clients browser needs to process the received data (presumably in javascript), which can mean a little "halt" if the received data is too big, or client has not so much ram memory.

However, if you are looking for fast tables, which can be filtered in place, without refresh, with fast pagination and search, and your tables are not going to be really big (few thousand rows per page), I would really go with Ajax.

To be more specific, XXXX.php which you fetch using ajax, should generate json response, which you later would parse in javascript and put content where it belongs. Json is standard, and it has function in php and javascript, which makes it perfect for these kinds of tasks.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I have not thought of the latest way to use JSON, i might consider it for future change since most of my code is done but since i'm experiencing some speed issues starting to explore a bit.

Since as of now i'm using AJAX functions to call from file which echos the results that i need but i find it really slow and the first thing that came to my mind is the one that you mentioned that the browser has to do extra work to receive and print them out.

My tables are not going to be more that 1000 rows. Therefor i think i will go with AJAX only on cases where i need auto-refresh like livescores

Comment: Also, when you use JSON as a method of communication, you can use received data in ajax, to populate existing elements. Which means, that if you need to update some number, you can surround each number in `<span id="number1">99</span>` and then after you receive new number in ajax request you just do `$('#number1').text(newNumber);` (jQuery), which eliminates the need to create and remove existing html elements.